# How to detect / forbid elements to overlap over iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have script that launches my website's iframe on various 3rd party websites.

I need to detect elements that overlap over the iframe to avoid iframe's misusage - e.g. covering iframe partially with some buttons.

The only reliable approach I can think of is periodically running `getBoundingClientRect()` for every element of the page to ensure nothing overlaps. But that sounds like very heavy calculations which I would like to avoid.

I've added code snippet with scam button example - how could I detect / solve this issue efficiently and reliably?

```js
const frame = document.createElement('iframe')
frame.src = 'https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/'
document.querySelector('.frame-container').append(frame);
```

```css
.frame-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scam-button {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #2a5e9a;
  z-index: 33312312312;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 20px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.scam-button img {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#scam" class="scam-button">Join 1000000$ draw by <img src="https://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/TR/2016/logos/W3C" /></a>
<div class="frame-container"></div>
```

Comment: Even if you had perfect code to prevent this, there would be nothing to stop someone from not using your specific JS to load the iframe, instead just doing it themselves, circumventing any anti-abuse measures you put in place.

Comment: @Qwerasd I agree, but the loader script is 20Kb of code - not so easy to launch without it, as of now I need to cover scenario when my script will include anti-abuse check

Comment: Well, in theory you don't need to check every element periodically, you can simply check for overlap for any new or updated elements, using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - which in most cases should significantly improve the performance over brute force constant checks. Of course you'll have to brute force check everything if the frame itself changes, and make sure to also include checks after [`animation events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#using_animation_events)

Comment: MutationObserver sounds reasonable, but I found out if I just compare x/y of elements - it is not enough, z is also important as iframe could be opened in modal / popup, with z it becomes much more complex